# Testing Site Redirect Controller that is used by several Sites

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, community

I have several community portals on an org and I have a central controller that performs some page redirects, based on several things. User type/settings/etc to decide which page a user lands on after registering or logging in.

The easiest way I found to do this was to chunk out logic based off of the `Site.getMasterLabel()`. But now that I am trying to cover this controller with test code I can't figure out how to set the `Site` in the test code so that I can test the different logic blocks. Then send them where they need to go (and/or have access to) based off of their profile (and other things).

**Simplified Controller:**

```
public class RedirectController {

    public PageReference redirect() {
        String siteLabel = Site.getMasterLabel();
        PageReference pageRef;
        String profileName = [Select Profile.Name From User Where ProfileId = :UserInfo.getProfileId()][0].Profile.Name;

        if (siteLabel.equalsIgnoreCase('SITE 1 Name')) {
            pageRef = site1RedirectLogic(profileName);
        } else if (siteLabel.equalsIgnoreCase('SITE 2 Name')) {
            pageRef = site2RedirectLogic(profileName);
        }...

        return pageRef;
    }

    private PageReference site1RedirectLogic(String profileName) {
        //logic
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

**Test Class Method:**

```
@isTest
static void test_RedirectController () {
    //How to set Site???
}
```

So after login I send them to a dummy page to action this method and get them where they need to be. My problem being in my test code I cannot figure out how to set the `Site` to the site I am testing.

Is there a way I can set the `Site` in my test class?

Or, should I let this piece go and simply test the logic blocks?

I know I can `Test.setCurrentPage(page)` for testing the pages individually and I do have some pages (especially the login/register flows) that are used across sites with minor dynamically driven content based off of the `Site`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to convert `if`/`else` chains to a `Map` if I can.

Any time you're scratching your head trying to figure out how to test something, consider the `Separation Of Concerns` pattern. Also here where your method does not need to consider any state from your controller, you might as well go `static`.

```
public static PageReference getRedirect(String siteLabel)
{
    return redirects.containsKey(siteLabel) ? redirects.get(siteLabel) : someFallback;
}
@TestVisible static Map<String, PageReference> redirects
{
    get
    { // might as well lazy load the data you need here
        if (redirects == null)
            redirects = new Map<String, PageReference>
            {
                '<value_1>' => method1(runningUser.Profile.Name),
                '<value_2>' => method2(runningUser.Profile.Name)
            };
        return redirects;
    }
    private set;
}
static User runningUser
{
    get
    { // lazy loading again
        if (runningUser == null)
            runningUser = [
                SELECT Profile.Name FROM User
                WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()
            ];
        return runningUser;
    }
    private set;
}
```

With the above pattern, you don't really care what the value of `Site.getMasterLabel` gives you. You can test the behavior you want specifically, which is the routing. Then you can trust that `getRedirect(Site.getMasterLabel())` will *also* behave as you expect.

Comment: Thank you. Any benefit in lazy loading when the load is going to happen once and only once anyway?

Comment: @Jesse just idepotence.

Comment: @JesseMilburn Actually during executions where you don't reference it your code will execute faster. Specifically with unit tests I would think this aspect relevant.